# How to stop Application Insights from logging handled exceptions generated in jquery?

Tags: jquery, azure-application-insights

I have a web app in Azure for which I've turned on Application Insights.  In my app I use the Progress/Telerik Kendo for JavaScript API, version 2017.3.1102 which is bundled with jQuery 1.12.3.

Application Insights is logging handled exceptions from jQuery, exceptions which are documented here as purposeful: https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14123

I'd like to stop these from being logged by AI.  I'm trying to troubleshoot an obscure security token issue so I want logging to be expansive, but these handled exceptions are generating thousands of entries per hour in my Application Insights logs.

Is there a way to exclude specific JavaScript files or APIs or 'handled' exceptions from being logged?

Comment: Take a look at [ITelemetryProcessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#filtering-itelemetryprocessor), this is for c#. You can search the usage in other SDK like js etc.

Comment: In addition to using a telemetry processor, you could also disable automatic exception collection by the SDK and implement your own which just calls `trackException`. This is basically what the [app insights onerror handler](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/blob/937826606db47058655c90e7c88d4140286d152a/extensions/applicationinsights-analytics-js/src/JavaScriptSDK/ApplicationInsights.ts#L421) looks like anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you choose to go the TelemetryProcessor route you can implement your telemetry processor which would examine the event and filter out unwanted events.  Returning false from the telemetry processor when a condition is met would filter out the event.
Thanks Ivan for linking the ITelemetryProcessor documentation.  I realized that the documentation doesn't have details on how to implement filtering in JavaScript.  Will update it now.

Here is a sample showing how one could implement filtering:

1. Define the filtering function:

```
var filteringFunction = (envelope) => {
  if (envelope.data.someField == "tobefilteredout") {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
};
```

2. Add your telemetry initializer callback:

```
appInsights.addTelemetryInitializer(filteringFunction);
```

Comment: Can you show some of the code from the link and also include the link for TelemetryProcessor to this answer? Just in case the site is blocked for some people and it is easier for others to find the answer.

Comment: Can you also include the link?